# SELECT execute([]) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in

Tags: php, pdo

I'm adding `[]` this symbol within an execute() in PDO, and it returns error.

I'm working in WAMP5

```
 $sqlStatement="
  SELECT * 
  FROM $table_results 
  WHERE title = ? AND id_category = ?
  ";    

   $stmt = $bdConection->prepare($sqlStatement);
   $stmt->execute([$title, $id_category]);
   echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

It works well if I delete `WHERE title = ? AND id_category = ?` and `[$title, $id_category]` bur returns more results, instead of adding those ... then
IT RETURNS:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in

Comment: Please post the full error message, and also, are you sure this problem is actually reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this error with PHP 5.2. Documentation about PHP array's [syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax) states:

> ... As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which
>   replaces array() with []. ...

What you can do in your case is to define an array using `array()`:

```
<?php

$sqlStatement = "
  SELECT * 
  FROM $table_results 
  WHERE title = ? AND id_category = ?
";    

...
$stmt = $bdConection->prepare($sqlStatement);
$stmt->execute(array($title, $id_category));
echo $stmt->rowCount();
...

?>
```

Comment: or upgrade to the latest PHP version ofcourse